# Client host rejected: cannot find your hostname + SMTP

Tags: centos, smtp, dovecot, exim, spamassassin

I have a VPS configured with dovecot. Now for some of the mails that I send are rejected with the following error:

Any Clues?

Comment: Why did you remove the actual error message? Without the error, the question is totally useless and likely to be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure so-called "reverse zone" for your domain name. Usually VPS control panel have DNS-related tools where you have to set PTR record pointing to your IP-address.

While you do not set PTR record properly other mail servers will treat you as spammer and reject messages from you.

Comment: the vps is on digital ocean. It has the options for adding zone records like A. Is there something specific called PTR record in panel?

Comment: "..The hostname you choose for your droplet is set as the PTR record for its IP address.."

Comment: well that is already set then!

Comment: any other reason you see for this?